# Glitch in html5lib?

Tags: python, html5lib

I'm getting this error. Is it a bug or is it a code error? What does it mean?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "isc.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests, os, sys, bs4
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'
```

(i upgraded html5lib bs4 and requests)

Comment: Please post your code, we don't have context

Comment: Try to upgrade beautifulsoup4 and html5lib

Comment: I edited https://github.com/trevorw22/Imgur-Scraper/blob/master/imgurScraper.py (code at https://pastebin.com/i8UD5Dbf)

Comment: @干猕猴桃 I actually forgot to upgrade pip (fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue related to your html5lib package version try upgrading it.